# Android SharedPreferences not removed until app is restarted

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, logout

I'm stucked with this problem.
In my app I use **SharedPrefManager** as a singleton class, in order to keep some "session" information. In this simple example app I just save the user's name and a boolean that indicates whether or not the user is logged in to skip the login screen if already logged, or to show it if not.
When starting the app, after the splashscreen, the **LoginActivity** is started.
At this point, if the user has already logged in before (without logging out later, that means the boolean value of *isuseradded* SharedPreferences variable is *true*), the user is redirected to the **MainActivity**, otherwise he sees the login form, where he can insert username and password and make a REST API request to a remote server.
If the login is correct, the **MainActivity** starts and simply shows the name of the user, taken from the response JSON obtained by the remote login REST API call.
Now, here is my problem: I want to implement a simple logout feature that deletes (or changes, as in this test app) all the information stored by SharedPreferences and takes the user back to the LoginActivity.
But when I click logout, the values for SharedPreferences are updated only in MainActivity, while in LoginActivity they remain the same as before, so when the user is redirected to LoginActivity, the *isusedadded* shared preference is still *true*, and the user is redirected back to MainActivity.
But SharedPrefManager class is a singleton, so its values should be the same in every part of the app, because only one instance of it exists, so why do I have this behavior?

You can test the app by downloading the full app code [here](http://www.stefanopace.net/temp/SharedPrefApp.zip) and using these credentials for login:

**Username:** 52346

**Password:** 32fjueM1 (case sensitive)

Here follows my code.

**App.java:**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class App extends Application
    {
     private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
     private static App mInstance;

     @Override
     public void onCreate()
        {
         super.onCreate();

         mInstance = this;
        }

     public static synchronized App getInstance()
        {
         return mInstance;
        }

     // This method returns the queue containing GET/POST requests
     public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
        {
         if(mRequestQueue == null)
            {
             mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            }

         return mRequestQueue;
        }

     // This method adds a GET/POST request to the queue of requests
     public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req)
        {
         getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }
    }
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);

         finish();
        }
    }
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
     private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

     Button loginButton;
     EditText userIDInput, passwordInput;
     TextView loginErrorMsg, title;
     LinearLayout bgLayout;

     SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this);

         Log.i("HERE", "LoginActivity onCreate: "+sharedPrefManager.isUserAdded());
        }    

     @Override
     protected void onResume()
        {
         super.onResume();

         sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this);

         Log.i("HERE", "LoginActivity onResume: "+sharedPrefManager.getUserName());

         // if the user is already logged in
         if(sharedPrefManager.isUserAdded())
            {
             Log.i(TAG, "User is logged in");

             // if the device is connected to the internet
             if(Utils.isDeviceOnline(this))
                {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

                 finish();
                }

             // if the device is offline
             else
                {
                 Log.i(TAG, "Internet connection is not available");
                }
            }

         // if the user is not logged in
         else
            {
             Log.i(TAG, "User is NOT logged in");

             setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

             title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
             loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_errorText);
             userIDInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_id_paziente);
             passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
             loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_submitButton);
             bgLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_parentLayout);

             // Bind a custom click listener to the login button
             loginButton.setOnClickListener(new LoginButtonClickListener(this));

             // Bind a custom click listener to the background layout
             // so that the soft keyboard is dismissed when clicking on the background
             bgLayout.setOnClickListener(new LoginBackgroundClickListener());
            }
        }
    }
```

**LoginButtonClickListener.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
     private Context context;
     private SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

     public LoginButtonClickListener(Context c)
        {
         this.context = c;
        }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
        {
         sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context);

         // if internet connection is available
         if(Utils.isDeviceOnline(context))
            {
             // Verify login credentials from DB
             doLogin();
            }

         else {}
        }

     // check login data with REST API
     private void doLogin()
        {
         final String paziente_id = ((EditText)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.login_id_paziente)).getText().toString();
         final String paziente_password = ((EditText)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.login_password)).getText().toString();

         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest
            (
             Request.Method.POST,
             "http://www.stefanopace.net/iCAREServer/api/v1/index.php/login",

             new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String s)
                    {
                     try
                        {
                         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                         if(!obj.getBoolean("error"))
                            {
                             String name = obj.getString("nome");

                             sharedPrefManager.addUser(name);

                             Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                             context.startActivity(intent);
                            }

                         else
                            {
                             Toast.makeText(context, "Error on JSON response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                     catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },

             new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)
                    {
                     Toast.makeText(context, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })

            {
             @Override
             protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
                {
                 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                 params.put("id_paziente", paziente_id);
                 params.put("password", paziente_password);

                 return params;
                }
            };

         App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
    }
```

**LoginBackgroundClickListener.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.view.View;

public class LoginBackgroundClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
        {
         Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(v);
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
     private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

     TextView personName;

     SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;    

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         personName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.person_name);

         Log.i(TAG, "Value: "+sharedPrefManager.isUserAdded());

         personName.setText(sharedPrefManager.getUserName());
        }

     @Override
     protected void onResume()
        {
         super.onResume();

         sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this);

         Log.w("MainActivity", "onResume");
        }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

         return true;
        }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
         switch(item.getItemId())
            {
             // Logout button has been pressed
             case R.id.logout_action:
                {
                 Log.i("Logout pressed", "Logout button has been pressed!");

                 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");

                 alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton
                    (
                     "Yes",
                     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                            {
                             boolean success = sharedPrefManager.removeDataFromSharedPreference();

                             // if the operation is OK
                             if(success)
                                {
                                 // go to the login activity
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);

                                 finish();
                                }

                             else
                                {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );

                 alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton
                    (
                     "No",
                     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                            {}
                        }
                    );

                 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                 alertDialog.show();

                 return true;
                }
            }

         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**SharedPrefManager.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public final class SharedPrefManager
    {
     private static final String TAG = "SharedPrefManager";

     private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
     private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

     private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;

     private static final String SHARED_PREF = "sharedprefs";

     private static final String KEY_IS_USER_ADDED = "isuseradded";
     public static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";

     private SharedPrefManager(Context context)
        {
         sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

         sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new LocalSharedPreferencesChangeListener());
        }

     public static SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context)
        {
         if(mInstance == null)
            {
             mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
            }

         return mInstance;
        }

     // add an user to the shared preferences
     public boolean addUser(String name)
        {
         editor.putString(KEY_USER_NAME, name);
         editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_USER_ADDED, true);

         return editor.commit();
        }

     public boolean removeDataFromSharedPreference()
        {
         editor.putString(KEY_USER_NAME, "HELLO");
         editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_USER_ADDED, false);

         return editor.commit();
        }    

     public String getUserName()
        {
         return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, "");
        }

     public boolean isUserAdded()
        {
         return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_IS_USER_ADDED, false);
        }
    }
```

**Utils.java**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;    

public class Utils
    {
     public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view)
        {
         InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }


     // This method checks if the device is connected to the Internet
     public static boolean isDeviceOnline(final Context context)
        {
         final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

         if(connectivityManager != null)
            {
             final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

             boolean isOnline = (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());

             if(!isOnline)
                {
                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                 alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                 alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                 alertDialog.setMessage("Internet is not available");

                 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                         // Reload the Activity
                         Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
                         ((Activity) context).finish();
                         context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                 alertDialog.show();
                }

             return isOnline;
            }

         return false;
        }
    }
```

**LocalSharedPreferencesChangeListener**

```
package mypackage.sharedprefapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocalSharedPreferencesChangeListener implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    {
     @Override
     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
        {
         Log.i("HERE", key);
        }
    }
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_id_paziente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_errorText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login error"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_submitButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mypackage.sharedprefapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**splashscreen.xml** (in drawable resources folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**mainmenu.xml** (in res/menu resource folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/logout_action"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    ...

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage.sharedprefapp">

    <!-- Needs internet to connect to Google Services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Permission to check internet connection state -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:process=":other_process"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle** (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: create a method public type in SharedPrefManager.java   and add this code SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().commit(); and call on logout.

Comment: you can add  it on logout action editor.putBoolean("KEY_IS_USER_ADDED", false);

Comment: In my _removeDataFromSharedPreference_ method in _SharedPrefManager.java_ I have this code that is called on logout:

`editor.clear();
return editor.commit();`

where editor is defined as _SharedPreferences.Editor_ .
Is it the same? If yes, it doen't work for me :(
Or better, it works, but only if I restart the app.

Comment: @ashish I tried that too, not working for me :(

Comment: When you log out, what is the behaviour of the app right now?

Comment: @fluffyBatman Now when I logout, the app is redirected to the LoginActivity, but the boolean value of isuserlogged is still true, so the userò is redirected to MainActivity again. Instradare, if I close the app and then open it again, the SharedPreferences are no longer there. It's as if the SharedPreferences removal is delayed somehow. But the onSharedPreferencesChange eventi is triggered...

Answer (score 1):

Just call **editor.clear();**
and **editor.commit();**
is enough to delete all data from shared preference.

Comment: Yes, I read this in every forum, but I don't understand why is not enough for my app :(

Answer (score 0):

Because `onResume`, you keep on instantiating a new `SharedPrefManager`

`sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);`

Modify your `SharedPrefManager` so that it only gives one instance at all times OR make sure that you are referring to the same object when you return to LoginActivity.

Comment: Ok, l'll give a try and I'll let you know! Thanks

Comment: Changed my code to have one instance of SharedPrefManager. _App_ singleton class:
`public class App extends Application
    {
     private static App mInstance;
     private SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         mInstance = this;
         sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);
        }

     public SharedPrefManager getSharedPrefManager(){
         return sharedPrefManager;
        }

     public static synchronized App getInstance(){
         return mInstance;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is permanent storage, you can clear

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().commit();
```

alternate solution
   you want once app close clear entire values,try [Application singleton class](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Comment: Maybe I make some mistake on managing SharedPreferences... I use a SharedPrefManager class where I declare a SharedPreferences object and an Editor for it. Then, in my code I use that manager to use the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

@Ciammarica you can call this code on click of Logout button, hope this can help you..you can set in logout button boolean value false..

SessionManager.setUserLoggedIn(YourActivity.this, false);                                      SessionManager.clearAppCredential(YourActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

I Changed my code in order to have only one instance of SharedPrefManager class.
This is my *App* singleton class:

```
public class App extends Application
    {
     private static App mInstance;
     private SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         mInstance = this;
         sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);
        }

     public SharedPrefManager getSharedPrefManager(){
         return sharedPrefManager;
        }

     public static synchronized App getInstance(){
         return mInstance;
        }
    }
```

Then from other classes I get the instance by calling

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = App.getInstance().getSharedPrefManager();
```

Now, with this change, the *onSharedPreferenceChanged()* event is triggered only once, so this is better than before, but the "delayed" behavior is still there... I mean, even if I use editor.clear(); and editor.commit(); methods, the values are updated but I can see them only if I close and open the app again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself... It didn't like the *sharedPrefManager.removeDataFromSharedPreference();* method to be called from inside *new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()*

I took it in another part of the code and it worked.